# Creating a android app that sends POST request to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json, http-post

I've already tried several options to send a post request from an android app to a server running a PHP file
I need to send a POST Request where the following parameters: id = 0 & balance = 666

I have the following code on my app and wen the app goes to send the request the app crashes

Can some one help?

ANDROID CODE:

```
package com.example.hk300.jsonpost;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import static android.R.id.message;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Remove the below line after defining your own ad unit ID.
    private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
            + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";

    private static final int START_LEVEL = 1;
    private int mLevel;
    private Button mNextLevelButton;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private TextView mLevelTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the next level button, which tries to show an interstitial when clicked.
        mNextLevelButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.next_level_button));
        mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
        mNextLevelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showInterstitial();
            }
        });

        // Create the text view to show the level number.
        mLevelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
        mLevel = START_LEVEL;

        // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId (defined in values/strings.xml).
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();

        // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
        Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Proceed to the next level.
                goToNextLevel();
            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goToNextLevel();
        }
    }

    private void loadInterstitial() {
        // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
        mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void goToNextLevel() {
        // Show the next level and reload the ad to prepare for the level after.
        mLevelTextView.setText("Level " + (++mLevel));
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
        new BackgroundTask().execute();

    }

    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
//Do UI operation here and onPostExecute
             //TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.credits);
             //textview.setText(message);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            OutputStream os = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            String contentAsString = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://disjunct-swabs.000webhostapp.com/testapp.php");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("id", "0");
                jsonObject.put("balance", "666");
                String message = jsonObject.toString();
                //You cannot perform these UI operation on non-UI thread

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /*milliseconds*/);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                wr.writeBytes(message);
                Log.e("JSON Input", message);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                conn.connect();
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                contentAsString = is.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("shit", "Shit");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("shit", "Shit");
            } finally {

                conn.disconnect();
            }
            //return response to onPostExecute()
            return contentAsString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res){
            //Do anything with response

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: can you post the specifics of the error, like the logcat message?

Comment: the logcat only shows this :                                                                                                               new connection
04-16 17:49:32.709 1609-1609/system_process W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection

Comment: 04-16 17:49:36.447 2405-2894/com.google.android.gms I/FA-SVC: App measurement is starting up, version: 10298
04-16 17:49:36.481 2405-3007/com.google.android.gms I/FA-SVC: This instance being marked as an uploader

Comment: You should put your error information **into** your question; not into comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are not running this in the main UI thread. Create a new thread or use AsyncTask to perform network operations.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("https://disjunct-swabs.000webhostapp.com/testapp.php"); 

        JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
        postDataParams.put("id", "0");
        postDataParams.put("balance", "666");
        Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                       InputStreamReader(
                              conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

}
In the above thread, you cannot declare, initialize or perform operation(setText) on any view, because they must happen on UI thread only. Put that in onPreExecute or onPostExecute methods
Now you cun run the code by

```
new BackgroundTask().execute();
```

Also add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you are using Android M or above, you must ask permission during runtime as well. This should be your goToNextLevel() method

```
private void goToNextLevel() {
    // Show the next level and reload the ad to prepare for the level after.
    mLevelTextView.setText("Level " + (++mLevel));
    mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        }, 10);

     }
    }
    new BackgroundTask().execute();

}
```

Comment: i'v tried to create a new tread and call it on the app oncreate, its stops the app from crashing but still doesn't send the data to the PHP. If it helps what i'm trying to archive is display an admob add to the user and then send to a DB (using a PHP file to handle the query) some info (the one above) so basically i'm using the standard template for admob from  android studio and implementing the code above to send the php post. then i call the code "trycon;" inside the "private void goToNextLevel()" that comes with the template.

Comment: I'v replaced my code with your async task but still doesn't work, i even removed the text view part, maybe its the post request that its not properly formed now , is there any way for me to see the post request being sent ?  Also i've tried running the code in a new java class, and on the main activity java

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: still doesn't work i must be doing something wrong, i just posted the full code above please see if anything is wrong. I also changed "String contentAsString = readIt(is,len);" to " contentAsString = is.toString();" it was giving me an error not recognizing len. (the code is on the mainactivity java)

Comment: I have given the complete code, check new editted answer

Comment: Thanks man now it works, was missing that & on the POST  :)